# .csv data into a dictionary in Python: Duplicate values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, duplicate-data

I'm attempting to turn .csv data into a dictionary in Python but I appear to be getting duplicate dictionary entries.

This is an example of what the .csv data looks like:

```
ticker,1,2,3,4,5,6
XOM,10,15,17,11,13,20
AAPL,12,11,12,13,11,22
```

My intention is to use the first column as the key and the remaining columns as the values. Ideally I should have 3 entries: ticker, XOM, and AAPL.  But instead I get this:

```
{'ticker': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
{'ticker': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
{'XOM': ['10', '15', '17', '11', '13', '20']}
{'ticker': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
{'XOM': ['10', '15', '17', '11', '13', '20']}
{'AAPL': ['12', '11', '12', '13', '11', '22']}
```

So it looks like I'm getting row 1, then row 1 & 2, then row 1, 2 & 3.

This is the code I'm using:

```
def data_pull():
    #gets data out of a .csv file
    datafile = open("C:\sample.csv")
    data = [] #blank list
    dict = {} #blank dictionary
    for row in datafile:
            data.append(row.strip().split(",")) #removes whitespace and commas
            for x in data: #organizes data from list into dictionary
                k = x[0]
                v = x[1:]
                dict = {k:v for x in data}
                print dict

data_pull()
```

I'm trying to figure out why the duplicate entries are showing up.

Comment: why is your second for loop inside the first one ? Just don't do that and that'll work just fine

Comment: It looks like that is the source of the problem. Changing the indents completely fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many loops; you extend `data` then loop over the whole `data` list with all entries gathered so far:

```
for row in datafile:
    data.append(row.strip().split(",")) #removes whitespace and commas
    for x in data:
        # will loop over all entries parsed so far
```

so you'd append a row to `data`, then loop over the list, with one item:

```
data = [['ticker', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
```

then you'd read the next line and append to `data`, so then you loop over `data` again and process:

```
data = [
    ['ticker', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
    ['XOM', '10', '15', '17', '11', '13', '20'],
]
```

so iterate twice, then add the next line, loop three times, etc.

You could simplify this to:

```
for row in datafile:
    x = row.strip().split(",")
    dict[x[0]] = x[1:]
```

You can save yourself some work by using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

def data_pull():
    results = {} 

    with open("C:\sample.csv", 'rb') as datafile:
        reader = csv.reader(datafile)
        for row in reader:
            results[row[0]] = row[1:]

    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop `for x in data` should be outside of the loop `for row in datafile`:

```
for row in datafile:
    data.append(row.strip().split(",")) #removes whitespace and commas
for x in data: #organizes data from list into dictionary
    k = x[0]
```

Or, `csv` module can be your friend:

```
with open("text.csv") as lines:
    print {row[0]: row[1:] for row in csv.reader(lines)}
```

A side note. It's always a good idea to use the raw strings for Windows paths:

```
open(r"C:\sample.csv")
```

If your file was named, e.g, `C:\text.csv` then `\t` would be interpreted as a `tab` character.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in `csv` module:

```
import csv

output = {}

with open("C:\sample.csv") as f:
    freader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in freader:
        output[row[0]] = row[1:]
```